# Change string to a date format in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

```
x = (input("month: "), input("day: "), input("Year: "))
```

month:  11
day:  1
Year:  2016
('11', '11', '2016') <---- how can I convert this in to this 11/01/2016 format?

Comment: There are mainly two ways to go. You could use `"/".join(x)` to connect the tuple to one string, or you could feed the month/day/year into [Python's datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the functionalities of the datetime module, you can simply go:

```
>>> x = input("month: ") + '/' + input("day: ") + '/' + input("year: ")
month: 11
day: 01
year: 2016
>>> x
'11/01/2016'
```

If you want to make it look pretty and pythonic:

```
>>> x = "%s/%s/%s" % (input("month: "), input("day: "), input("year: "))
month: 11
day: 01
year: 2016
>>> x
'11/01/2016'
```

Datetime won't help you here, as it's formatting applies mostly to time math.